# How to insert an R coordinates list into rmapshaper for creating a polygon

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a Geolocation polygon according to a list of coordinate or data frame into rmapshaper package. I tryed some different approach to solve this issue with no success. To be more specific convert the list into "coordinates" as variable.
My list output:

```
[
  [39.9912, 116.316],
  [39.9912, 116.3153],
  [39.9911, 116.3145],
  [39.9911, 116.3136],
  [39.9911, 116.3127],
  [39.9912, 116.3127],
]
```

However, according to some example it should be like this:

```
poly <- structure('{
 "type": "Feature",
 "properties": {},
 "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
   "coordinates": [[
     [-70.603637, -33.399918],
     [-70.614624, -33.395332],
     [-70.639343, -33.392466],
     [-70.603637, -33.399918]
   ]]
 }
}', class = c("json", "geo_json"))
ms_simplify(poly, keep = 0.1)
```

Any thoughts?
-Gilad

Comment: Does it really have to be a a solution for the rmapshaper package? Or can it also be a sf-solution?

Comment: You say it's your "list output". Can we see your list?

Answer (score 0):

sf solution

```
library(sf)
x <- st_sfc( st_polygon( list( rbind( c( 39.9912, 116.316 ), 
                                      c( 39.9912, 116.3153 ), 
                                      c( 39.9911, 116.3145 ), 
                                      c( 39.9911, 116.3136 ), 
                                      c( 39.9911, 116.3127 ),
                                      c( 39.9912, 116.3127 )
                                      )
                               )
                         ), 
             crs = st_crs(4326),
             check_ring_dir = FALSE)

plot(x, axes = TRUE, graticule = TRUE)
```

[image]